ROS Noetic on a raspberry pi
I am a newbie and I am trying to ultimately interface with a ROBOTIS open-manipulator x. I am following the quickstart guide to get ROS noetic installed, and up to now have been using raspberry pi OS, although ubuntu 20.04 is suggested. Perhaps that is my issue. However, whenever I run the install ros noetic file as they do in the quickstart guide, I always seem to get the error that catkin_init_workspace command is not found as well as catkin_make. After that when I run source ~/.bashrc, there are no files or directories found in both my catkin_ws/devel as well as opt/ros/noetic.
I have tried to install ubuntu and it just absolutely will not be recognized on boot by the raspberry pi. Any guidance would be appreciated

Sorry slight confused. You say you have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on the Pi. But then say
"I have tried to install ubuntu and it just absolutely will not be recognized on boot by the raspberry pi".
Is the Pi booting ubuntu or not?

Noetic is Ubuntu 20.04, which can be found in the rpi-imager.
The installation steps all work on the ROS wiki.
